# Disable a specific ESLint rule when fixing on save with VSCode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, formatting, eslint, create-react-app

I'm trying to disable eslint's fixing on save for a specific rule when using vscode. In practice I'd like React hooks' dependency array issues to be **shown to the user but not fixed**. This is my settings.json:

```
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": false
    },
    "[javascriptreact]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": false
    },
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll.eslint": true,
    },
    "eslint.codeActionsOnSave.rules": [
        "!react-hooks/exhaustive-deps",
        "*"
    ],
    "eslint.validate": ["javascript", "javascriptreact"]
}
```

I would expect eslint to show a warning when I break the exhaustive deps rule, but leave it there when I save the file. Instead my code is still fixed on save, what am I doing wrong?

*(note: the hooks dependencies rule shouldn't be broken, but I'm working on an existing project, I can't review all existing hooks and I've already seen the code break because of hooks triggering when they shouldn't have because of ESLint's auto-fixing)*

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: No, I'm not working on that project anymore and I'm letting eslint do its thing on the new ones